# How to use a Mongo query in PHP?

Tags: php, database, mongodb

I have the following MongoDB query:

```
db.crimes.aggregate([
{ $match: {"CrimeLSOAName":/.*Bradford.*/} },
{
    $group: {
    "_id": "$CrimeType",
    "count": {
        $sum: 1
        }
    }
},
{
$sort: {
    "count": -1
}
},
{
    $limit: 10
}
])
```

Which outputs the ten most common 'CrimeTypes' where CrimeLSOAName field contains 'Bradford'. I am trying to use the query in PHP, my attempts are below but the query does not run correctly. If someone could give some help it would be appreciated.

Trying to use in PHP:

```
$top10Crimes = array(
array('$match') => array('CrimeLSOAName:/.*Bradford.*/'),
array(('$group') => array('_id' => '$CrimeType',
                     'count' => '$sum: 1')),
array('$sort') => array('count' => '-1')
array('$limit' => '10')
);

$result = $collection->aggregate($top10Crimes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is invalid, this should work. It usually helps to format your array similar to the pipeline you have in the mongo shell.

```
$top10Crimes = array(
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            'CrimeLSOAName' => '.*Bradford.*/'
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => '$CrimeType',
            'count' => array(
                '$sum' => 1
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$sort' => array(
            'count' => '-1'
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$limit' => '10'
    )
);
```